# php-html-parser How to follow redirects

Tags: php, html-parsing

https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser
Anybody knows how to to follow redirects in this library?
For example:

```
require "vendor/autoload.php";
use PHPHtmlParser\Dom;
$dom = new Dom;
$dom->loadFromUrl($html);
```

Comment: In the most trivial way - by using a different library to make the request and get the final result, and then using `loadStr` instead …

Comment: Or pass in your own `ClientInterface` in the `loadFromUrl` call, and use one that is set to automatically follow redirects.

Comment: As @CBroe points out they rely on the [Guzzle Client](https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html) which could be created and passed in to allow redirects which is the default behavior

Comment: But how to do it? @hppycoder Can you gimme example?

Comment: @theblackpost yes, i can give you an example. What is the URL you are trying to use? Is it publicly available?

Comment: Oh this is fun! It's not as straight forward as we thought and I'm working on it now. I will detail below with my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Versions:**

- guzzlehttp/guzzle: "7.2.0"
- paquettg/php-html-parser: "3.1.1"

**Why does the library not natively allow redirects?**

The `loadFromUrl` method has the following signature (at the time is 3.1.1)

```php
    public function loadFromUrl(string $url, ?Options $options = null, ?ClientInterface $client = null, ?RequestInterface $request = null): Dom
    {
        if ($client === null) {
            $client = new Client();
        }
        if ($request === null) {
            $request = new Request('GET', $url);
        }

        $response = $client->sendRequest($request);
        $content = $response->getBody()->getContents();

        return $this->loadStr($content, $options);
    }
```

Looking at the line `$response = $client->sendRequest($request);` it goes to Guzzle's Client - https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/Client.php#L131

```php
/**
* The HttpClient PSR (PSR-18) specify this method.
*
* @inheritDoc
*/
public function sendRequest(RequestInterface $request): ResponseInterface
{
   $options[RequestOptions::SYNCHRONOUS] = true;
   $options[RequestOptions::ALLOW_REDIRECTS] = false;
   $options[RequestOptions::HTTP_ERRORS] = false;

   return $this->sendAsync($request, $options)->wait();
}
```

The `$options[RequestOptions::ALLOW_REDIRECTS] = false;` will automatically turn off redirects. No matter what you pass in with the Client or Request it will automatically turn off redirects.

**How to follow redirects with the library**

Observing that the method `loadFromUrl` will make the request and get the response then use `loadStr` we'll mimic the same but use Guzzle (as it's a dependency of the library).

```
<?php
// Include the autoloader
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\GuzzleException;
use PHPHtmlParser\Dom;

include_once("vendor/autoload.php");

$client = new Client();
try {
    // Showing the allow_redirects for verbosity sake. This is on by default with GuzzleHTTP clients.
    $request = $client->request('GET', 'http://theeasyapi.com', ['allow_redirects' => true]);

    // This would work exactly the same
    //$request = $client->request('GET', 'http://theeasyapi.com');
} catch(GuzzleException $e) {
    // Probably do something with $e
    var_dump($e->getMessage());
    exit;
}

$dom = new Dom();
$domExample = $dom->loadStr($request->getBody()->getContents());
foreach($domExample->find('a') as $link) {
    var_dump($link->text);
}
```

The code above will instantiate a new Guzzle Client, and make a request to the URL allowing redirects. The website used in this example is a site that will 301 redirect from non-secure to secure.